# Numpy ImportError using Sublime Text with Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, importerror

`ImportError` trying to import `numpy` in Sublime Text3 with Anaconda Distribution

I´m trying to import Numpy in Sublime Text3 with Anaconda Distribution. I´ve already set my Build System to Anaconda´s path and Numpy works well in all anaconda´s IDE packages.

Sublime Build System:

```
{
"path":"C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\",
"shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
"file_regex": "^[]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Syntax Check",
        "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
    }
]
}
```

```
import numpy as np

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module can not be found.

I expect to import the module correctly, but shows the error:

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem on my Windows 10, SublimeText 3 64-bit and Anaconda3 64-bit running `conda` Sublime Text package. Here is a workaround:

You can try reinstall the `numpy` python package in the working python environment (env). For example, if you're working on `mypython` env, open the Anaconda Command Prompt and do this:

`conda activate mypython`

then use `pip` to reinstall `numpy`:

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`

then try again in Sublime Text, thing should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. After hours of not finding a solution, this was such a simple one

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I tried everything.

- different build systems codes.
- modify syspaths.
- installing python from python.org
- re-install sublime text.
- even downloading the DLL files from weird sources.

In the end only re-installing anaconda and re-writing the syspaths fixed the problem in my case.